# Is a preposition of place required when replacing "where" with "that"?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, that

A preposition appears to be needed when *that* is used in sentences such as:

> That's the store **where** I bought my computer.
>   That's the store **that** I bought my computer (*at*?).

with exceptions occurring, per page 483 of *Oxford Practical English Usage*, for "*somewhere, anywhere, everywhere, nowhere, and place.*"

> That's the place **where** I bought my computer.
>   That's the place **that** I bought my computer (*at*?).

A comment on a [related question at ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34266/a-place-which-we-can-stay-or-a-place-which-we-can-stay-in) states:

> In practice, most native speakers wouldn't get bogged down in prepositions and relative pronouns here - we'd just say "We need a place to stay". But for no specific reason that I can identify, if I replace place with house there it seems to require the preposition: "We need a house to stay in".

I agree with the notion that the preposition is required following *that*. What I can't do is wrap my head around exactly why that should be.

**What difference is there between *where* and *that* in these sentences that calls for the omission of a preposition when using *where* and the inclusion of a preposition when using *that*?**

Comment: "That's the store (that) I bought my computer **from**." "That's the place (that) I bought my computer **at**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it will help to transform the clauses to their equivalents that better show the syntax.  "That's the store *where I bought my computer*." becomes

> *Where did I buy my computer*? or
>  *I bought my computer there*.

No preposition of place is required with words like "where" and "there" that contain the notion of a place in their meaning.  "*That's the store that I bought my computer*" becomes

> *I bought my computer that*

which doesn't work with "that" serving as a conjunction with no other role in the clause. This works if the clause is a direct object:

> I didn't steal it.  Did you ever consider *that I bought my computer*?

but not if you want to modify "store."

You'll have to consult a linguist to answer the question of "place."  Perhaps it sufficiently names a location such that no preposition is required.  The *OED* has usages with "find," "have," "hold," "give," "make," and "take" that don't require a preposition, some of them going back to the 14th century, so perhaps we're just used to idiomatic expressions that contain the word without a preposition.