# Who vs. That/ Where vs. That

Tags: relative-pronouns

This is the teacher *that* we call "Hot Lips".
This is the the place *that* we read many books.

The examples using *that* instead of **who** and **where** respectively are being taught.  The pronoun **that** refers to the *teacher* and the *place*, yet my fellow instructor has continued allowing the students to use this relative-pronoun despite my advice.

Is there **any** way you could argue these sentences are grammatically correct?

Comment: I suppose you could take heart from the "accepted" answer on [Should you use “who” or “that” when talking about multiple people doing something?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427/), saying ***Who** refers to people. **That** and **which** refer to groups or things.*. But bear in mind that more *upvotes* went to the answer saying *They are interchangeable.* I don't think you'll find a lot of support for (largely, *outdated*) pedantry here.

Comment: And the other question is addressed at [Is a preposition of place required when replacing “where” with “that”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262649/is-a-preposition-of-place-required-when-replacing-where-with-that). But I don't think the answer given there is definitive.You can't say 'This is the room that we read many books', but _place_ seems to have a grammar all of its own. 4 of the first 10 Google hits for "this is the place that we" have the 'that-for-where' usage (the rest being of the form 'this is the place that we call our home' etc).

Answer (score 1):

***Who vs that***

With human head nouns it's a free choice between wh-relatives and that-relatives: "the teacher who we call 'Hot lips'" and "the teacher that we call 'Hot Lips'" show no semantic differences, and no syntactic differences other than what follows from "that" not being a pronoun ("the teacher to whom the letter was sent" is grammatical but *"the teacher to that the letter was sent" is of course not).

***Where vs that***

"Where" and "that" are frequently interchangeable when the relativised word is an adjunct of place, as in "a place where/(that) you can relax". But in sentences with head nouns less likely to suggest location, a wh-relative would normally be required. For example "this is the article where the claim was made" is fine, but not *"this is the article (that) the claim was made".